# Custom 404 for media files in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

Is there a a way to create a custom 404 page for files in the Media directory of Orchard? I would like to show a specific error messages when somebody tries to download a file from a specific path (/Media/Default/MySpecificFolder/) that no longer exists. Right now if a file does not exist it just renders a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orchard uses StaticFileHandler for images(anything in the media folder), css and js files among others. 
there was a chap who tried to create 'SEO' routes for assets. have a look in the modules gallery.

All said, it seems a bad idea to put assets behind too much logic in the days where more people are using CDN or buckets to provide images to their websites and alleviate the load on the server.

You could go oldskool and override the handler. i used to do it all the time, back in webforms. here is some code that seems like the real thing:[StaticFileHandler](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/StaticFileHandler@cs/2/StaticFileHandler@cs)

Perhaps leave the handler alone for the main web.config but override the ones in the folders you might like to serve your special 404 page.

I do not know why would you need something like that, but go for it.

thinking about it, you could create a shape that would abstract the functionality you are after. Im thinking on the sides of documents mostly, cos i still struggle with the images...

Your shape will tokenise the document in route which will pick up an id or url and if the file does not exists redirect to a 404, but if it exists just send the file.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks ErMasca. This makes sense. The reason why we would like this is that users submit a form and a file is generated for them in the media library in a specific path. They are then sent to a page with a message and a download link and an email with the link is sent as well. A task then runs and finds the files that are 60 days or older and deletes them. If they are deleted and the user tries to download the file we would like to tell the user to re-submit the form.

Comment: defenitely use a controller for that. have a look in orchard for the way you validate your email account. it uses something call "nonce", (its a crytographic term..dont worry too much). 
the last time a look at it, it didnt store the string but you could easily use it without it or finish it urself. 

Do NOT override the StaticFileHandler please

Comment: Yep, you made me realize how stupid this idea was when I can just have a controller with a query string param that returns the right file or shows a message or redirects. I think I was overthinking it.